# i&& was unexpectes at this time CMD WINDOWS

Tags: windows, cmd

Why if I write in the `CMD` windows:

```
FOR /F %%i IN ('DIR "C:\FOLDER\*txt."')
```

I get this error?

`i&&`  was unexpected at this time

Comment: You mean `"%%i" is unexpected...`? `%%i` is for use in batchfiles. On command prompt use only one percent-sign: `%i`

Comment: but when i try to use "%i" i get the error: the syntax of the command is incorrect

Comment: the complete syntax is: `for ... %i in (...) do ...` Do you have a "do"? (for example `.... do @echo %i`)

Comment: the bash file is :FOR /F %%i IN ('"C:\Users\myfolder\*shp."') DO (
    SET infile =%%i
    SET outfile=!infile:.shp=.tif! ......

Comment: With this FOR-Syntax you enumerate the output of the DIR-Command. I Assume that is not what you want. I assume you want to enumerate the files. Use this Syntax:   for %i in ("C:\FOLDER\*.txt") DO ( ... )